# Querying process by CommandLine

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wmic

I'm trying to do the following query in WMI:

```
SELECT ProcessID from Win32_Process where CommandLine='C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe'
```

But I got an "Invalid query" error. I also tried with:

```
SELECT ProcessID from Win32_Process where CommandLine='C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe'
```

And still get the same error, also I tried to change the single quotes to double quotes but it didn't work.

Does anybody know if its possible to do that query?

Comment: I am looking in WMI Code Creator Process Command line for calc.exe and it's showing as just `calc`.  No exe, no path, just calc.  Confirm ?   I started calc.exe from cmd.exe in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.  Depends on how calc.exe is spawned.  For instance, when I type calc into cmd.exe window, my calc gets a commandline of 'calc'.  When I type calc into powershell.exe console, it get's a full path.   The Win32_Process 'commandline' variable is not reliable IMO.  Here are some differing result to prove my point.

```
cmd.exe                              4028 C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /K set
calc.exe                             2580 "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
notepad.exe                          3612 "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
cmd.exe                              2864 "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
conhost.exe                           480 \??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe
WMIC.exe                             3596 wmic
WmiPrvSE.exe                         2272 C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiprvse.exe
cmd.exe                              2296 "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
conhost.exe                          3708 \??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe
notepad.exe                          1284 "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
calc.exe                             1736 calc
powershell.exe                       3136 "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```

So to make it work you will need an OR clause in your SQL statement, matching 'calc' or "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"

Answer (score 0):

In addition Windows adds sometimes an additional `whitespace` into the command line after the `ExecutablePath` and before the first parameter.

Even if there is no paramter and the Executable was lanched with quotes (because of `whitespaces` in the path) then in most cases the command line is the `ExecutablePath` and a final `whitespace` at the end.

That cost me some hours to find this. 
Cheers!