# how to exit Powershell when a process is still running?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, scripting, cmd, teamcity

I have a powershell script, which start a java application through a batch file.

the powershell doesn't exit because the java (processs) is still running,

I cant use taskkill because I need the java to keep running,

the process is automated with TeamCity so I can't just close the CMD window manually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not make the session go invisible - see kludge here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717535/determine-if-script-is-running-hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i used the Winexe [tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/),
which allows you to start cmd command from Linux to windows machine.
and ran the batch with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `Start-process` CmdLet to start your java process ?

Comment: i've tried and it opens the process on another CMD window, which never closes and i cant use the flag /wait=false because it closes the window before the Java is even starting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `java` from powershell directly, you could try:

```
cmd /c java.exe <your stuff>
```

Which should allow it to start the java process and end the powershell script.

Comment: I need to call it from powershell because its a remote server, so i can't use cmd.

Comment: Can you make powershell call a bat script on the remove server that has the `cmd /c java.exe <your stuff>` in it?

Comment: I can, and i did. but it doesn't close the CMD beacause the java is still running